# C# initializing an integer data type

Tags: c#, variables

how to initialize a variable of data type integer, in C#. the problem is the variable has to store an integer with values ranging from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an enum, which typed as an Int32 (int) by default. E.g.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    ThirdValue,
    FourthValue
}
```

Obviously you can call the enum whatever you like, and give the four values meaningful names.  Then you can just initialise an instance as so:-

```
var myValue = MyEnum.FirstValue;
```

Comment: An enumeration does not constrain values, since all integer values are stil valid.  The following wil work just fine:

var MyValue = (MyEnum)(-1);

Comment: I know that, but at least an enum states the intention.

Answer (score 2):

int x = 1;

You may be wanting an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.80).aspx) that is constrained values.

Answer (score 2):

For a static member variable assign at declaration:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    Static int myVar = 1;
}
```

For a local method variable assign at declaration:

```
void MyFunc ()
{
    int myVar = 1;
}
```

For member variable assign at declaration or in the constructor

```
public class MyClass
{
    int myVar;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myVar = 1;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, to restrict to the range 1..4 you have to protect it with a property set like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    int myVar = 1;

    public int MyVar
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set 
        { 
            if( value < 1 || value > 4) throw new Exception();
            myValue = value; 
        }

    }
}
```